# CNN model why is ReLu used in Conv1D layer and in the first Dense Layer?

Tags: nlp, convolutional-neural-network, convolution, activation-function

I have a problem. I have a CNN model which is used for an NLP problem. This is written in Python. I have questions about this, which I can't find an answer to.

- Why is ReLu used inside the Conv1D layer and not Softmax ?
- Why is ReLu used again as activation function in the first Dense-Layer and why Softmax afterwards ?

````py
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(
        Embedding(vocab_size
                ,embed_size
                ,weights = [embedding_matrix] #Supplied embedding matrix created from glove
                ,input_length = maxlen
                ,trainable=False)
         )
model1.add(Conv1D(256, 7, activation="relu"))
model1.add(MaxPooling1D())
model1.add(Conv1D(128, 5, activation="relu"))
model1.add(MaxPooling1D())
model1.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model1.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model1.add(Dense(number, activation='softmax'))
print(model1.summary())
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The softmax activation is used as the activation function of the last layer in multiclass classification problems because it gives a categorical probability distribution over N discrete options.

ReLU is used as a middle-layer (either convolution or dense) activation function because it is a non-linearity that works well and is robust to the vanishing gradient problem (as opposed to tanh or sigmoid).